# Tachanun during Torah reading

Tags: halacha, tefilla

One is supposed to say Tachanun and cover their face while in the presence of a Torah scroll (SA 131:2 in Hagah). This is usually while it is still in the Aron. I once heard however that you shouldn't say Tachanun when the Torah scroll is out, especially during the Torah reading. Is this true? I didn't see this mentioned in SA or MB

Comment: Shouldn't say Tachanun at all or just say it while seated without falling forward? Please edit to clarify

Comment: I believe I heard that covering your face in front of the sefer Torah is disrespectful, but like I said I don't know of any source. I would guess simply saying it during the Torah reading is inappropriate since everyone must listen to the Torah reading

Comment: This may fall under the general concept that one should be listening to the Torah reading and not davening. Did you hear that the rule specifically mentions Tachanun?

Comment: Yes, and it was more the face covering while the Torah is out

Comment: well you should be listening to leining...

Comment: @robev "I believe I heard that covering your face in front of the sefer Torah is disrespectful" Can you edit that into the question?

Comment: @Laser123 The question is when the Torah is out - not necessarily during *Leining*.

Comment: If it means anything I just saw a big talmid chacham say Tachanun during the Torah reading.