# Slow at Full Tachanun - keep going?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tachanun

I am slower than the shlichei tzibbur in my shul at Full Tachanun (Shacharis Mon, Fri). I usually get about half-way through by the time they start taking the Sefer out.

Do I keep going, ignoring the taking out sefer section?

Do I just pause for the kria and keep going in between leining and after?

Assuming it is correct to keep going in tachanun, if the sefer is being walked to the bima and I am during nefilas apaim, should I stand? Stand and lean on a shtender with nefilas apaim?

If I know I can't make it through all of tachanun by sefer time, should I skip parts to ensure I arrive on time?

Comment: I think any way you choose is fine; just make sure to stand when the Torah is escorted from the aron to the bima and listen to the kria. You may skip parts of tachanun if it will increase your concentration on the rest of the tefila.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28020/catching-up-when-saying-tachanun-m-th https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82248/tachanun-during-torah-reading

Comment: The best way is to ask the rav of the shul you are davening in. He can explain the minhag of that particular shul.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23490/im-in-the-middle-of-tachanun-when-they-take-out-the-torah-what-do-i-do